# Ruby - array of hashes, deduplicate keys, preserve values in array where keys deduped

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, duplicates

how to get from arr to arr_result ?

```
arr = [ {a => 1}, 
        {a => 2}, 
        {b => 3}, 
        {b => 4},
        {b => 10},
        {c => 12}, 
        {c => 16},
        {d => 7}  ]

arr_result = [ {a => [1,2] }, 
               {b => [3,4,10] },
               {c => [12,16] },
               {d => 7  } ]
```

Deduplicate the keys, and preserve the values of those keys, in arrays, where dedup occurs. Preserve keys/values where deduplication doesnt occur, ( as seen with { d => 7 } in the example )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not a valid ruby object in the first place.

```
arr = [ {a: 1}, 
        {a: 2}, 
        {b: 3}, 
        {b: 4},
        {b: 10},
        {c: 12}, 
        {c: 16},
        {d: 7}  ]

arr.
  map(&:flatten).
  group_by(&:shift).
  each { |_, v| v.flatten! }
#⇒ {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 4, 10], :c=>[12, 16], :d=>[7]}
```

---

To get exactly what you wanted:

```
arr.
  map(&:flatten).
  group_by(&:shift).
  map { |k, v| v.flatten! && { k => v.size == 1 ? v.first : v } }

#⇒ [{:a=>[1, 2]}, {:b=>[3, 4, 10]}, {:c=>[12, 16]}, {:d=>7}]
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. ( invalid ruby object - yes, my bad, i used => instead of : in error )

Answer (score 0):

You could also reduce each hash into an new hash and merge as you go like this:

```
arr.reduce({}) do |memo,h| 
  memo.merge!(h) {|_,o,n| Array(o) << n}
end
#=> {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 4, 10], :c=>[12, 16], :d=>7}
```

Then an `Array` value is only created if a second value is added.

Your intended result is very unconventional but you can achieve your desired result by appending `.map {|k,v| {k=> v}}` to the above resulting in:

```
arr.reduce({}) do |memo,h| 
  memo.merge!(h) {|_,o,n| Array(o) << n}
end.map {|k,v| {k=> v}}
#=> [{:a=>[1, 2]}, {:b=>[3, 4, 10]}, {:c=>[12, 16]}, {:d=>7}]
```

Normally you would want what @mudasobwa's original methodology returns which is a single hash of `key => Array` for all elements which makes it far easier to loop through. You could also obtain this same result with

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) do |h,obj|
  h.each {|k,v| obj[k] << v}
end
#=> {:a=>[1, 2], :b=>[3, 4, 10], :c=>[12, 16], :d=>[7]}
```

Another way to get your current desired result:

```
arr.reduce([]) do |memo,h|
  key,value = h.first
  if r = memo.detect {|nh| nh.key?(key)}
    r[key] = [*r[key],value]
  else  
    memo << h 
  end
  memo
end
#=> [{:a=>[1, 2]}, {:b=>[3, 4, 10]}, {:c=>[12, 16]}, {:d=>7}]
```